# Get the muc users with the affiliation owner using the strophe js muc plugin

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe, multiuserchat

Hello I'm using the muc plugin and trying to get the muc user with the affiliation of 'owner'. i have tried doing this using the onRoster call back which is added when joining a muc.

```
$scope.XMPPConnection.muc.join(room, $scope.facebookId, onMessage, onPresence, onRoster, '', {maxstanzas : 0} );


    function onRoster(roster) {
        if($scope.justConnected)
        {
            $scope.owner = getOwner(roster);
            getTrackList();
            $scope.justConnected = false;
        }
    }




function getOwner(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("getting the owner");

        for (var p in data) {
             console.log(p + "are you the owner? ")
             if( data[p].affiliation === 'owner') {
                 return ( p + '@xmpp.url.com' );
              }
         }

       console.log("finishing the owner");
    }
```

When printing the roster data to the console I get all of it but I only get one with a message saying that it is a snapshot. When expanded it has all the occupants.

```
Object {422733867925336: Occupant}
```

Am I going about this the right way. It seems like the object isn't fully populated when I try to get the owner and is missing so occupants. Why is this?